# Как из ответа в постмане полученный id сохранить в переменную

Tags: postman

Задаю запрос и в  теле ответа получаю

`{ "data": [ { "id": 36, "phone": "79115556623", "email": "test@link.ru", "surname": "Иванов", "first_name": "Иван", "rating": "5.00", "active": false, "blocked": false,      } ], "current_page": 1, "total": 1 }`
В разделе Tests
нужно написать скрипт, в котором бы я сохраняла id пользователя в переменную и использовала его в следующих запросах

Я в написании тестов в постмане новичок. Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Изучите сниппеты http://joxi.ru/zANlKyMcxMJapm. Там есть основные методы и проверки